# Error loading sdk.dll from Python 36

Tags: python, python-3.6

I try to load dll from Python 36 and getting the below error.

How can I fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SDK_communicator.py", line 3, in <module>
    sdkDll = WinDLL("C:\jhgsdk.dll")
  File "c:\python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found


from ctypes import *
sdkDll = WinDLL("C:\sdk.dll")

I also tried:
  C:\\sdk.dll
  C:\sdk.dll
  C:/sdk.dll
```